# No idea what's happening in my profile!

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

[image]

What does this imply? I don't get up votes once I reach **160 reputation** for a question? Is this very common. There are **23 events** and the reputation stopped just after **16** up votes.(*Laughs*) A bug need to be fixed in my account?

Comment: Inceptio: I got 37 upvotes today, including 18 from this question myself.  The upvotes still count toward badges and stuff.  In any case, be proud: a lot of people like what you had to say!

Comment: Like a [reputation](http://youtu.be/-DdfLtOrBPU?t=30s) bazooka.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Congratulations, you have [hit the daily reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it). Tomorrow you will see that you've earned a [shiny new badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/41/mortarboard) if you haven't already.

Comment: Woah! Was not aware of it. There will be **no** points awarded if you score $200$ in a day(According to the article)?

Comment: @Inceptio No *extra* point over the cap! You do get everything up to it! There are exceptions though - you can still be awarded bounties, and I think you still get the points from accepted questions.

Comment: Well, bug fixed then. ;)